# What programming languages can produce the "choose file" screen?

Tags: file, filesystems

What programming languages can produce the "choose file" screen as shown below? How do they do it?

["Choose file" screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95ZNC.png)

Answer (score 0):

This can usually be produced with a file dialogue (at least that's what its called in C#) and for higher up languages you will need to find a library that supports this (these exist in many languages), as for lower level languages you will need to look into creating gui windows from scratch and then usually setting some type parameters which would cause it to look like that.